# Delete files with a similar names, matching a range

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have multiple similarly named file. The difference in their name is just an incremented number. For example linux kernels:

```
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic           3.2.0-29.46                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic           3.2.0-31.50                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic           3.2.0-32.51                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic           3.2.0-33.52                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic           3.2.0-34.53                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic           3.2.0-35.55                             Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP  
.... and more of them
```

I would like to remove most of them. Say, from 29 to 35. There are too much to remove manually using `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic`. What script should I write?

Comment: What did you try so far? What tools are you familiar with?

Comment: @Bex Only manual deletion 1 by 1. I updated the question.

Comment: Please try to do some research of your own before you ask questions. Have a look at `find` for example.

Comment: I have one doubt: is the text you posted a list of different files or some text in a file? Also, what's the pattern of those files you want to delete?

Comment: In my example I saying `file` several times:) I got the above output by running `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`. So no text lines here

Answer (score 1):

You can delete files based on its name pattern. For example, do:

```
rm linux-image-3.2.0-{29..35}-generic
```

Before, and to make sure you are deleting the right thing, do execute the command with `ls` to see which files will be affected.

Comment: +1 but this is the content of a file..not files, Ithink he wants to remove those lines

Comment: Thanks, but there are some missing numbers eg. 31 goes after 29 and missing 30 gives an error.

Comment: you can use:`rm linux-image-3.2.0-{29..35}-generic 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @leemour despite the error, it should delete properly. Just redirect to `/dev/null` if you don't want to see it... oops, MortezaLSC just said it :)

Comment: I am using `sudo apt-get purge` so configuration files are removed with kernels. And unfortunately it doesn't delete the files.

Comment: But the question is, @leemour , where are these files? Because if you know the path and filenames, then you can delete them.

Comment: can't you do: `rm linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic && rm linux-image-3.2.0-{31..35}-generic` ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first line:

```
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-01-generic           3.2.0-29.46
```

and this is your 40th line:(for example)

```
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic           3.2.0-29.46
```

So you can use `awk` to delete specific lines:

```
awk -v m=29 -v n=35 'm <= NR && NR <= n {next} {print}' test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking about file names.